# Gensim similarity query-returns ids and values of vectors-no string

Tags: python, gensim

I am trying to use gensim for some topic modelling. When I print the similarity queries, I only get it the id's and values instead of the actual strings. How do i print the string of my similarity queries ? 
below is the code i am using.

```
index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(lsi[corpus]) 
sims =index[vec_lsi] # perform a similarity query against the corpus
print(list(enumerate(sims))) # print (document_number, document_similarity)
```